# MongoDB unwind in find()? and Performance better in find() queries?

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I have this aggregate query, which takes really long to get results and I only need the Aggregation framework because of the $unwind parameter. To be specific I have to query things that are in an array. How can I rewrite this aggregation query into a find query and do you think performance would be better with find?

```
db.cms.aggregate([{"$unwind":"$values"},
                       {"$match": {"values.timestamp":{"$exists":1}}},
                       {"$match": {"values.sensor":"V1"}},
                       {"$match": {"values.timestamp":{"$gte":"2018-02-07 14:00:16.163","$lte":"2018-02-07 14:00:16.163"}}}] )
```

The documents in the collection look like this

```
_id" : ObjectId("5a8ac17569191602538b65d2"), 

"values" : [
    {
        "sensor" : "B", 
        "unit" : "mm/s2", 
        "timestamp": "2018-02-07 14:00:16.163"

    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : "Bp", 
        "unit" : "mm/s2", 
        "timestamp": "2018-02-07 14:00:16.163"
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : "Bt", 
        "unit" : "mm/s2",
        "timestamp": "2018-02-07 14:00:16.163"
    }, 
    {
        "sensor" : "V1", 
        "timestamp" : "2018-02-07 14:00:16.163", 
        "unit" : "V" 

    }]}
```

Comment: I dk if you will have a better performance without the aggregation but you should take a look at the performance of the query and understand why it's taking to long. Take a look at the explain() function

Comment: @Graciano I already took a look at explain() and it uses no Index although I created a compound index on "values.timestamp" ,"values.sensor" and Single Indexes on the two of them. Now I guess that maybe the unwind with aggregation doesnt really work with indices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is filtering out, simply use the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operator:

```
db.cms.aggregate([
{
    $project: {
        values : {
            $filter: {
                input: "$values",
                as: "value",
                cond: {
                    $and: [
                        { $ifNull: [ "$$value.type", false ] },
                        { $eq: [ "$$value.sensor", "V1" ] },
                        { $eq: [ "$$value.timestamp", "2018-02-07 14:00:16.163" ] },
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
])
```

By the way, the `cond` field of the aggregational `$filter` operator requires an expression that resolves to a boolean value. We cannot use 
the `$exists` nor any query operator, and its aggregational equivalent is the `$ifNull` operator.